# Latex table combine columns using tabularray package

Tags: tables, tabularray

I am trying to convert this to a latex tabular and merge the "JastAdd" column with two rows the top row is a single column "JastAdd" and the bottom row is two columns one for "time" and one for "memory". The design for "APS (without monotonicity check)" and "APS (with monotonicity check)".

[image]

CSV:

```
file size in MB,nodes,non-terminals,terminals,JastAdd time,JastAdd memory,APS (without monotonicity) check time,APS (without monotonicty check) memory,APS (with monotonicity) check time,APS (with monotonicty check) memory
279,9075268,8192,9067076,JVM crashed after 1670 seconds,JVM crashed after 1670 seconds,861,18362,-,-
29,3596625,4096,3592529,893,4713,246,5052,-,-
21,1024167,2048,1022119,127,993,72,1288,31716,2946
11,265762,1024,264738,15,368,9.3,479,3324,774
5,67244,512,66732,2.8,126,2.3,137,348,344
2,17045,256,16789,0.8,63,0.6,78,33,98
```

Latex:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tblr}
{
colspec      = {X[c,m]X[c,m]X[c,m]X[c,m]X[c,m]},
cell{1}{2,4} = {c=2}{},
cell{1}{1}   = {r=2}{},
hlines,
vlines,
}
file size in MB   &   nodes   &   non-terminals   &   terminals   &   JastAdd time   &   JastAdd memory   &   APS (without monotonicity) check time   &   APS (without monotonicty check) memory   &   APS (with monotonicity) check time   &   APS (with monotonicty check) memory \\
279   &   9075268   &   8192   &   9067076   &   JVM crashed after 1670 seconds   &   JVM crashed after 1670 seconds   &   861   &   18362   &   -   &   - \\
29   &   3596625   &   4096   &   3592529   &   893   &   4713   &   246   &   5052   &   -   &   - \\
21   &   1024167   &   2048   &   1022119   &   127   &   993   &   72   &   1288   &   31716   &   2946 \\
11   &   265762   &   1024   &   264738   &   15   &   368   &   9.3   &   479   &   3324   &   774 \\
5   &   67244   &   512   &   66732   &   2.8   &   126   &   2.3   &   137   &   348   &   344   \\
2   &   17045   &   256   &   16789   &   0.8   &   63   &   0.6   &   78   &   33   &   98  \\
\end{tblr}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you use software such as Microsoft Excel to create effects? Your textual description is a bit confusing.

Comment: @Clara updated the screenshot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tblr}
{
rows           = {valign=m},
columns        = {co=-1,halign=c},
hspan          = minimal,
cell{1}{1-4}   = {r=2}{},
cell{1}{5,7,9} = {c=2}{},
cell{8}{5}     = {c=2}{},
cell{7}{9}     = {r=2,c=2}{},
hlines,
vlines,
}
file size in MB & nodes   & non-terminals & terminals & JastAdd                        &             & APS (without monotonicity) check &             & APS (with monotonicity) check &             \\
                &         &               &           & time (seconds)                 & memory (MB) & time (seconds)                   & memory (MB) & time (seconds)                & memory (MB) \\
2               & 17045   & 256           & 16789     & 0.8                            & 63          & 0.6                              & 78          & 33                            & 98          \\
5               & 67244   & 512           & 66732     & 2.8                            & 126         & 2.3                              & 137         & 348                           & 344         \\
11              & 265762  & 1024          & 264738    & 15                             & 368         & 9.3                              & 479         & 3324                          & 774         \\
21              & 1024167 & 2048          & 1022119   & 127                            & 993         & 72                               & 1288        & 31716                         & 2946        \\
29              & 3596625 & 4096          & 3592529   & 893                            & 4713        & 246                              & 5052        & -                             &             \\
279             & 9075268 & 8192          & 9067076   & JVM crashed after 1670 seconds &             & 861                              & 18362       &                               &             \\
\end{tblr}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Small variation of nice Clara answer (+1), with use of `siunitx` package for formatting of numbers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \sisetup{group-minimum-digits=4}
\begin{tblr}
{
colspec        = {X[si={table-format=2.0}] X[si={table-format=7.0}] X[si={table-format=4.0}] X[si={table-format=7.0}]
                  X[si={table-format=3.1,minimum-decimal-digits=1}] X[si={table-format=4.0}] X[si={table-format=3.1,minimum-decimal-digits=1}]
                  X[si={table-format=4.0}] X[si={table-format=5.0}] X[si={table-format=4.0}]},
hspan          = minimal,
cell{1}{1-4}   = {r=2}{},
cell{1}{5,7,9} = {c=2}{c},
cell{8}{5}     = {c=2}{guard, c},
cell{7}{9}     = {r=2,c=2}{guard, c},
rows           = {m},
row{1,2}       = {guard, c, m},
hlines,
vlines,
}
file size in MB 
    & nodes   & non-terminals & terminals & JastAdd         &               & APS (without monotonicity) check &                & APS (with monotonicity) check &             \\
    &         &               &           & time (seconds)  & memory (MB)   & time (seconds)                   & memory (MB)    & time (seconds)                & memory (MB) \\
2   & 17045   & 256           & 16789     & 0.8             & 63            & 0.6                              & 78             & 33                            & 98          \\
5   & 67244   & 512           & 66732     & 2.8             & 126           & 2.3                              & 137            & 348                           & 344         \\
11  & 265762  & 1024          & 264738    & 15              & 368           & 9.3                              & 479            & 3324                          & 774         \\
21  & 1024167 & 2048          & 1022119   & 127             & 993           & 72                               & 1288           & 31716                         & 2946        \\
29  & 3596625 & 4096          & 3592529   & 893             & 4713          & 246                              & 5052           &  ---                          &             \\
279 & 9075268 & 8192          & 9067076   & JVM crashed after 1670 seconds 
                                                            &               & 861                              & 18362          &                               &             \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]